# Am I allowed to set SMS server for trial number?

Tags: numbers, sms, server, twilio, trial

I tried editing the URL for SMS POST/GET but a prompt asks if I want to release the number?

Comment: Hey John, I've noticed this recently and will report it properly. Try clicking the save button instead of pressing enter and that should work for you.

Comment: Hi @philnash I'm stuck trying to get this [very first SMS example working.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey) I have a twilio trial account, a twilio number that can send/receive SMS and I have verified my personal phone number. Every time I send a test text I keep getting a response to configure my number's SMS URL even though I already have. I am stuck on what is going wrong. I followed instructions exactly, PHP file matches exactly, and I am hosting it in Heroku. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? Twilio seems great but doesn't offer tons help on troubleshoot

Comment: Hi @SMT, can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with your account sid and I'll take a look.

Comment: @philnash I'm sorry but it was a stupid mistake all along! There was a typo in my code, I left out the closing PHP `?>`  in my PHP file where the URL was pointing which is what was causing it to break. Its always the dumbest mistake, isn't it! I appreciate the response though, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can only send from numbers or short codes purchased from Twilio.

If you're in a trial you can use the trial phone number as the From parameter but you need to verify the numbers used in the To field before being able to send to them.

To verify a number go here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified